# how to validate google recaptcha in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, recaptcha

```
public class GoogleReCaptchaChecker {

        @Value("${google.recaptcha.url}")
        private String url;

        @Value("${google.recaptcha.secret-key}")
        private String secretKey;

        @Value("${google.recaptcha.site-key}")
        private String siteKey;

        @Autowired
        RestTemplate restTemplate;

        public Boolean validateGoogleReCaptcha(String reCaptchaResponseStr, String remoteAddr) {
            try {
                ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
                reCaptcha.setPrivateKey(secretKey);
                ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteAddr, siteKey, reCaptchaResponseStr);
                return reCaptchaResponse.isValid();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

This is my code for "google recaptcha" validation, but it always returns false,  I have no idea about what are the arguments need to be passed. is there any maven dependency to do ReCaptcha validation?. I'm using this  net.tanesha.recaptcha4j(version-0.0.7) dependency

Answer (score 1):

There is a Spring Boot starter project witch will validate reCAPTCHA for you.

You just have to set the captcha validated URLs in your config file.

More on GitHub: https://github.com/Mr-DeWitt/spring-boot-recaptcha